# problems with wstp32 (WSTP / mathlink)

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I've been recompiling old mathlink programs in Visual Studio 2013. No major problems so far until I got to a program that is seemingly similar to the others but that fails dramatically in the linking stage, generating a series of errors suggesting that WSTP32 was compiled with unusual settings.

[image]

Any suggestions for what might be causing this, and how I might get it to link?

Comment: [ March 2016 ] I have gotten this code to work in a new project. I'm not sure what precisely I was doing wrong in 2015 but it's likely that I had specified that Visual Studio build a Console application rather than a Windows application, among other problems.

Answer (score 2):

You are linking against the static library instead of the import library.  Remove the 's' from the wstp32i4s.lib that was supplied to link.exe.